# Filebeat restructure beat metadata fields

Tags: filebeat

I have following message generated. This is default structure generated by filebeat. Here the metadata is nested, I am looking for a way to restructure the beat fields to root level as shown in second example.

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-03-27T08:14:09.508Z",
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "stage-kube03",
    "name": "stage-kube03",
    "version": "5.2.1"
  },
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": {
    "message": {
      "activityType": null
  },
  "offset": 3783008,
  "source": "/var/log/audit.log",
  "type": "log"
}
```

would want to take beat fields a level up as shown below.

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-03-27T08:14:09.508Z",
  "hostname": "stage-kube03",
  "name": "stage-kube03",
  "version": "5.2.1"
  "input_type": "log",
  "message": {
    "message": {
      "activityType": null
  },
  "offset": 3783008,
  "source": "/var/log/audit.log",
  "type": "log"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of manipulation you could use the Logstash Output: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html